# PHP ini problem

Tags: php, ini, memory-limit

I have this error in a PHP based installation:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of
>   8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 98304 bytes) in
>   D:\vertrigo\VertrigoServ\www\dos\ana\libraries\test\domain\query\query.php
>   on line 804

I changed my php.ini `memory_limit` from `8MB` to `12MB`, however I am still receiving the error.

What is the problem?

Comment: Your PHP script is out of memory. You'd need to show some code and/or tell us what your script is doing for explanations why

Comment: it is suppose install the anahita social engine, i already did the configuration steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted

8 Megabytes sounds pretty low. WordPress for example will choke on anything under 12 MB even without plugins, and run smoothly with 16 MB or more.

I'm therefore going to boldly guess that your social engine simply needs more memory to run. See for example this answer on how to raise the memory limit: [Increase PHP Memory limit (Apache, Drupal6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386815/increase-php-memory-limit-apache-drupal6)