# why does the ini_set('memory_limit') doesn't work?

Tags: php, memory, ini-set

I am doing a file resizer feature, and when I use very high resolution images, I get this fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
 allocate 8884 bytes) in /path/resizer.php on line 35
```

(resizer.php is the resizer class)
Then, when I use ini_set('memory_limit', '64MB');

.. in front of the whole block: if (isset($_FILES....))
... And i get this fatal error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to 
allocate 8884 bytes) in path/resizerenter code here.php on line 35
```

Please note that the allocated memory has *decreased* while I requested an increase.
Please let me know if you know what is wrong.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting environment?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386815/increase-php-memory-limit-apache-drupal6

Comment: If you are on any environment you did not personally set up, you may not have the permissions to override php.ini. Also, you may not have any idea how much memory is in the system for you to make such a change.

Comment: Hi there, no Im on localhost for now.

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for your link. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the php.ini setting: memory_limit

Maybe is already more than 64M. In case you can

```
   ini_set('memory_limit', '128M'); or 256...
```

Operations with big images can happen to use huge memory!

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I realized, it it set to 32MB! I have a question, is RAM we are talking about? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes this is RAM. ini_set('memory_limit', '128MB') tells php engine that a single execution can use maximum 128MB of ram. This guarantees that a script happens to use to much memory causing problems to system's performance.